# github action throwing error at building mavenized tibco bw6 application

Tags: maven, github-actions, cicd

I am trying to run github action and build tibco bw6 application and deploy TEA, this is my github action yaml

#this is first pipeline

```
name: Tibco Workflow

on:
  
  pull_request:
    branches: [ development ]

jobs:
  
  Run-PSScriptAnalyzer-on-Windows:
    
    name: Run PSScriptAnalyzer on Windows
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Install PSScriptAnalyzer module
        shell: pwsh
        run: |
          Set-PSRepository PSGallery -InstallationPolicy Trusted
          Install-Module PSScriptAnalyzer -ErrorAction Stop
      - name: Get list of rules
        shell: pwsh
        run: |
          Get-ScriptAnalyzerRule
  build:
    needs: Run-PSScriptAnalyzer-on-Windows
    runs-on: windows-latest
    
    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set up JDK
      uses: actions/setup-java@v2
      with:
        java-version: 11
        distribution: 'adopt'
        cache: maven

    
          
    - name: Build BW6 Application
      run: mvn clean install
```

but it is throwing below error:

```
Error:  The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (D:\a\ee.entEvent.eventMsg.vendorNetcool\ee.entEvent.eventMsg.vendorNetcool). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
Error:  
Error:  To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Error:  Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
Error:  
Error:  For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
Error:  [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Github runner is a github hosted windows server and this path ((D:\a\ee.entEvent.eventMsg.vendorNetcool\ee.entEvent.eventMsg.vendorNetcool) does not even exist in the server, not sure if github action any specific place it clone repo content ( like jenkins store repo content in /home/jenkins/workspace)

Comment: Did you search `ee.entEvent.eventMsg.vendorNetcool` in your project?

Answer (score 0):

### Is your `pom.xml` in the root folder of the repository?

##### The path is what the default working directory could be.

Without specifying any other `working-directory:` (which can be set for the entire workflow, per job, or per step), the folder a step will execute in on the `windows-latest` runner *should* be like `D:\a\<reponame>\<reponame>`.

So `D:\a\ee.entEvent.eventMsg.vendorNetcool\ee.entEvent.eventMsg.vendorNetcool` would be the default `working-directory`, and exist, on a runner for a repository if the repository was named `ee.entEvent.eventMsg.vendorNetcool`

I imagine that if your repository were named that, you would be less inclined to say it shouldn't exist. But absent any other snippet, that would be why that was the location it reported running in.

##### You must have a `pom.xml` *somewhere*, though;

The `cache: maven` option on `actions/setup-java@v2` would cause that step to fail with a different message, if a `pom.xml` didn't exist *somewhere* in any nested folder under where it is running, but that is all it requires, that it can find a `**/pom.xml`, not necessarily in the root folder.

##### Run `mvn` in the folder the `pom.xml` exists in.

Although the java setup was happy with any `**/pom.xml` file, the `mvn ...` invocation will need to be run from the location that the `pom.xml` exists at. You can do this by setting the `working-directory:` to, e.g., `the/path/to/the/pom`.